# Checking internet connectivity in Android without ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Tags: android, network-programming

I would like to check the internet connectivity but avoid adding `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.
The application does ask for `INTERNET` permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to request that permission.  Otherwise you can try pinging a known IP.  It won't be 100% accurate though (if for some reason that IP is down or unreachable, it won't work).

Comment: mmm I guess `NetworkInfo .isConnected();` does the same? (pinging some ip?)

Comment: No, its going to ask the linux kernel if it has a connected interface.  Pinging an ip is a real hack.

Comment: Requesting the permission [results in a canceled installation](https://developers.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=9216387&cid=52279353).

Comment: Very, very rarely. And only by idiots who don't realize how necessary that permission is to so many apps. But you can safely ignore those 12 or so people. Now if you request my contact list, you better have a good reason